# Record-like data structure?

Tags: data-structures

I would need something like this:

```
\setfield{record1}{field1}{alpha}
\setfield{record1}{field2}{beta}
\setfield{record2}{field1}{gamma}
\setfield{record2}{field2}{delta}
\assign{record3}{record2}
\getfield{record1}{field1} % should expand to alpha
\getfield{record1}{field2} % should expand to beta
\getfield{record2}{field1} % should expand to gamma
\getfield{record2}{field2} % should expand to delta
\getfield{record3}{field1} % should expand to gamma
\getfield{record3}{field2} % should expand to delta
```

Is there a package for this? I could live without the `assign` command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essentially `\setfield` is a `\def` where the `c`ontrol `s`equence `name` is constructed using the first two arguments. `\getfield` merely sets the requested control sequence (no error checking is performed; `\csname` ... `\endcsname` returns `\relax` if the record/field does not exist).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\setfield}[3]{%
  \expandafter\def\csname #1@#2\endcsname{#3}%
  \listcsgadd{#1}{#2}%
}
\newcommand{\getfield}[2]{%
  \ifcsname #1@alias\endcsname
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\csname \csname #1@alias\endcsname @#2\endcsname
  \else
    \csname #1@#2\endcsname
  \fi}
\newcommand{\recordalias}[2]{\expandafter\def\csname #2@alias\endcsname{#1}}
\newcommand{\recordcopy}[2]{%
  \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{%
    \expandafter\edef\csname #2@##1\endcsname{\csname #1@##1\endcsname}}%
  \dolistcsloop{#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\setfield{record1}{field1}{alpha}
\setfield{record1}{field2}{$\beta$}
\setfield{record2}{field1}{gamma}
\setfield{record2}{field2}{$\delta$}

\recordalias{record2}{record3}
\recordcopy{record2}{record4}

\getfield{record1}{field1} % should expand to alpha
\getfield{record1}{field2} % should expand to $\beta$
\getfield{record2}{field1} % should expand to gamma
\getfield{record2}{field2} % should expand to $\delta$
\getfield{record3}{field1} % should expand to gamma
\getfield{record3}{field2} % should expand to $\delta$

\setfield{record2}{field1}{$\gamma$}

\getfield{record2}{field1} % should expand to $\gamma$
\getfield{record3}{field1} % should expand to $\gamma$
\getfield{record4}{field1} % should expand to gamma

\end{document}
```

Added are two types of assignments:

- *alias* via `\recordalias{<first>}{<second>}` - this makes the `<second>` record an alias for `<first>`;
- *copy* via `\recordcopy{<first>}{<second>}` - this sequentially copies all the fields from `<first>` into `<second>` using list processing provided by [`etoolbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox).

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. This one fits my needs best. Just curious: Could anyone think of a **copy** function for those records? May be difficult without having a list of possible field names.

Comment: @LasseKliemann: I've added some updates to the answer. It now provides and *alias* or a *copy* function.

Comment: I don't think you need the `\expandafter`s in `\getfield` and only the first in `\do` appears necessary.

Comment: It might be interesting to add that this is basically the underlying mechanism of key val systems like pgfkeys :)

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{readarray}
\begin{document}
\readarraysepchar{ }
\def\mydata{alpha beta gamma delta}
\readarray\mydata\myarray[-,2]% Read \mydata as 2 fields into 2-D \myarray
Cell (2,2) has \myarray[2,2]
whereas cell (1,2) has \myarray[1,2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

If the data is in a file, also no problem.  Note that `\readdef`, while reading the file, sets `\ncols` to the number of fields detected in the first row and can be used, instead of an explicit `2`, for the `\readarray`.  I also demonstrate the use of a different separator (comma instead of space) and show how the `*` option of `\readarray` will remove leading and trailing spaces.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{readarray,filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{mydatafile}
alpha, beta
gamma, delta force
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
\readarraysepchar{,}
\readdef{mydatafile}{\mydata}
\readarray*\mydata\myarray[-,\ncols]% Read \mydata as 2 fields into 2-D \myarray
Cell (2,2) has \myarray[2,2]
whereas cell (1,2) has \myarray[1,2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

**FINALLY**, if changing cell data on the fly is a requirement, I implement here the macro `\setfield\<array name>[<row>,<column>]{<data>}`:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{readarray}
\makeatletter
\gdef\setfield#1[#2,#3]#4{%
  \expandafter\gdef\csname\expandafter\@gobble\string#1[#2,#3]\endcsname{#4}}%
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\readarraysepchar{ }
\def\mydata{alpha beta gamma delta}
\readarray\mydata\myarray[-,2]% Read \mydata as 2 fields into 2-D \myarray
Cell (2,2) has \myarray[2,2]
whereas cell (1,2) has \myarray[1,2]

\setfield\myarray[1,2]{$\beta$}
Cell (1,2) now has \myarray[1,2].
\end{document}
```

[image]