# Can't get foreach to work with ifinlistcs

Tags: foreach, loops

Could anyone kindly explain why the `\ifinlistcs` is always false when I try to use `\foreach` to provide each test element? Of course, I can use `\dolistcsloop` as it is the recommended way to process the list structures of `etoolbox`, but I have my reasons (see below).

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}

\listcsgadd{myList}{elem0}
\listcsgadd{myList}{elem1}
\listcsgadd{myList}{elem2}
\listcsgadd{myList}{elem3}

% this doesn't work
\foreach \x in {elem0, elem..., elem4}{%
  \ifinlistcs{\x}{myList}{\x{} exists in list}{\x{} doesn't exist in list}\\
}

% this works
\renewcommand*{\do}[1]{%
  \ifinlistcs{#1}{myList}{#1 exists in list}{#1 doesn't exist in list}\\
}
\dolistcsloop{myList}

\end{document}
```

[image]

## Why not `\dolistcsloop`?

I actually would like to nest two `\dolistcsloop` to iterate through two lists. Unfortunately, I believe this means I have to nest two `\renewcommand*{\do}[1]{}` which I believe doesn't work (at least it didn't when I briefly tried). So I thought to use `pgffor`'s `\foreach` as a workaround where I use `\dolistcsloop` for the outer list and `\foreach` for the inner list.

Ultimately, I'm trying iterate through this type of [data record structure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/415705/207268) which I slightly modified to accommodate an additional list structure for each data record (e.g. a list of tasks where each task has a list of milestones). If I can get `\foreach` to work with `\ifinlistcs`, then I'll have a working solution for what I want to do (and is why I wanted to make this the focus of the question).

But if there are other ways to create a similar data record structure (i.e. list of data records, each data record has a number of data field-value pairs, and some data fields are lists) that can be fully iterated through, I'm also open to such solutions.

Comment: For possible reference later on: one of the "other ways" is to use a lua table, which can contain a field which is another lua table, and so on. This is how luatex does its font caching, for example. Could be an option if you end up with huge data, or need multiple iterations of multi-nested tables,

Comment: @Cicada thank you very much for this alternative. A few years ago, I was using luatex but the compilation was so slow. Perhaps something wrong with my setup, but I did a brief look up on lua tables and it was enough to convince me to reconsider. Looks like a very promising alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to expand `\x` before `\ifinlistcs` operates on its first argument.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}

\listcsgadd{myList}{elem0}
\listcsgadd{myList}{elem1}
\listcsgadd{myList}{elem2}
\listcsgadd{myList}{elem3}

% this works
\foreach \x in {elem0, elem..., elem4}{%
  \expandafter\ifinlistcs\expandafter{\x}{myList}
    {\x{} exists in list}{\x{} doesn't exist in list}\par
}

% this works
\renewcommand*{\do}[1]{%
  \ifinlistcs{#1}{myList}{#1 exists in list}{#1 doesn't exist in list}\par
}
\dolistcsloop{myList}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I was briefly playing around with `\expandafter` without really knowing what I was doing with no results. I'll have to read up on it later. I accepted this as the solution. If you have a chance, could you explain why you have two `\expandafter` and why they're positioned as you have them?

Comment: @Pyon TeX strictly operates from left to right. The first `\expandafter` causes the expansion of the second one, which causes the expansion of `\x`; the two tokend disappear in the process; next, `\ifinlistcs` is expanded and it finds its arguments as usual.

Comment: Got it. Thank you for the clear explanation.