# Collect information to render later

Tags: boxes, database, patching, data-structures

I am not sure I am using the right terms for describing what I want to do, so the title may be off.

I want to be able to use a custom command like for example `\PersonalData{Name}{Some Name}` but not render it immediately. Instead I want to use `\PersonalData` multiple times, storing the data and then at some point later (or if possible anywhere in the document) use another command `\RenderPersonalData` for example and render all the stored entries.

Is such a thing easily possible?

It would also be great, if I could somehow iterate over all entries and know, how many there are, so that I can define things like vertical space below, except for the last one. Or have even and odd entries rendered with different background color.

Right now I only have a custom command looking like this:

```tex
\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\RequirePackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}%  This is inside a `.cls` document class.

\newcommand{\DataLabel}[1]{\bfseries{#1}}

\newlength{\labelColumnWidth}
\setlength{\labelColumnWidth}{35mm}

\newlength{\columnSeparatorWidth}
\setlength{\columnSeparatorWidth}{5mm}
\newcommand{\columnSeparator}{\hspace*{\columnSeparatorWidth}}

\newcounter{PersonalDetailsCounter}
\setcounter{PersonalDetailsCounter}{0}

\definecolor{EvenRowBackgroundColor}{rgb}{0,0.96,0.96}
\definecolor{OddRowBackgroundColor}{rgb}{1,0,1}

\newcommand\PersonalDetailsEntry[2]{%
  \ifthenelse
      {\isodd{\value{PersonalDetailsCounter}}}
      {\colorlet{RowColor}{OddRowBackgroundColor}}
      {\colorlet{RowColor}{EvenRowBackgroundColor}}%
  \colorbox
      {RowColor}
      {%
        \parbox[t]{\labelColumnWidth}{\DataLabel{#1}:}
        \columnSeparator
        \parbox[t]
               {\dimexpr\linewidth-\labelColumnWidth-\columnSeparatorWidth}% TODO: calculate exactly and correctly
               {#2}}%
  \smallskip
  % Increase counter for personal details.
  \stepcounter{PersonalDetailsCounter}}
```

But at least one problem exists: I don't know when the last entry is and will have an unnecessary `\smallskip` at the end. If I knew how many entries there are and could check whether I am at the last one, this would not be a problem. This lead me to thinking maybe I could store them all somehow and then iterate over them to render them.

(I am sorry, I don't even know what tags to assign to this question. Things I considered: `define`, `command`, `data`, `register`. But some seem to mean something else or do not exist, so are probably wrong.)

Comment: there are lots of options, a high-level package is datatool, but you can also implement your own solution with the expl3 functions, e.g. with properties.

Comment: One other option is the list processing functionality from `etoolbox` (see the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/etoolbox/etoolbox.pdf) section 3.7) which I find flexible and easy to use.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Do you have any suggestions for better tagging of this question?

Comment: @Zelphir I added some tags (and removed the unrelated `register`. This can also help you find related questions, like https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/415699/record-like-data-structure for example (which is tagged `data-structures`).